# Node-Canvas Cairo build errors

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, cairo, pkg-config, node-canvas

I am getting errors installing cairo on OSX from source.  I am following this guide: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---OSX.  I can't find any reference to "x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0-pkg-config: File exists" on google (https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ie=UTF-8&q=%22x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0-pkg-config%3a%20file%20exists%22) I don't know how else to describe it other then showing you the output:

```
$ tar -zxf pkgconfig.tgz && cd pkg-config-0.28
$ ./configure --with-internal-glib && make install
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/local/bin/ginstall -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/local/bin/gmkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep

...
...

  CC       gwakeup.lo
  CC       gprintf.lo
  CC       glib-unix.lo
  CC       gthread-posix.lo
  CC       giounix.lo
  CC       gspawn.lo
  CCLD     libglib-2.0.la
echo   > glib-public-headers.txt.tmp && mv glib-public-headers.txt.tmp glib-public-headers.txt
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in .
  CC       pkg.o
  CC       parse.o
  CC       main.o
  CCLD     pkg-config
 /usr/local/bin/gmkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
  /bin/sh ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/local/bin/ginstall -c pkg-config '/usr/local/bin'
libtool: install: /usr/local/bin/ginstall -c pkg-config /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  install-exec-hook
cd /usr/local/bin && ln pkg-config x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0-pkg-config
ln: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0-pkg-config: File exists
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "make uninstall" first, and try again